# Pubsub Hook to Bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a data pipeline as flows: app engine publishes to pubsub pushes to BigQuery. In the example in the Docs https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-pub-sub , they have pubsub push to a worker hosted in AppEngine who then handles the data (in my case writing to the appropriate BigQuery table). However is it possible to have pubsub push directly via a subscription to a BigQuery table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, there is no automatic way to push data into BigQuery. The two options would be:

1. Write a subscriber that gets messages from a from Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription and writes them to BigQuery.
2. Use [Google Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) to read via a [Pub/Sub I/O](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io) and write via a [BigQuery I/O](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io).

Answer (score 2):

I am using Dataflow with Apache Beam to process PubSub Messages into BigQuery tables.

```
import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.io
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions, PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
import json

TOPIC = 'projects/your-project-id/topics/your-topic'
SUBSCRIPTION = 'projects/your-project-id/subscriptions/your-subscription'

options = PipelineOptions()
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = 'your-project-id'
google_cloud_options.job_name = 'your-beam-job'
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://your-bucket/staging'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://your-bucket/temp'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

class FormatDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    print({'data': json.dumps(element.attributes['data'])})
    return [{'data': json.dumps(element.attributes['data']), 'schema':element.attributes['schema']}]


with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as gcp:
  messages = (gcp | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=None, subscription=SUBSCRIPTION, with_attributes=True))
  #do some schema validation here and output errors 
  def printattr(element):
    print(element)

  lines = messages | beam.ParDo((FormatDoFn()))
  lines | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    'wf-us-virtualmedia-sandbox:jstafford_dataset.jstafford_table',
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)

  result = gcp.run()
```